# install angular.js in sails V1 project

Tags: angular, sails.js

I would like to know how to integrate angular into a sails project.
Is a simple installation with npm enough, should I modify pipeline.js, or should I integrate with bower?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with bower integration : follow this link https://github.com/smies/sails-generate-bower/blob/master/README.md